# Counting "mulstisets" on a given sequence.

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, multisets

*So, i have the following problem:*

Let $a_1, a_2, a_3, ..., a_n$ be an integer sequence. How many distinct sequences of size $1$ to $n$ can you make from $a$, given for each element $a_i$, there are $f_{a_i}$ elements equal to it on sequence $a$.

Note: The elements in the sequences need to be in the order they appear in sequence a.

*Example:* if $a = (1, 1, 2)$, the answer is $4$ (namely, $(1), (1, 1), (1, 2)$ and $(2)$).

So far i've attempted to work with some repeated permutations formulas, but i can't figure out a way to do it.

Comment: What does it mean to make a sequence from $a$? Also when you say "there are $f_{a_i}$ elements equal to it on sequence a", do you mean the element $a_i$ appears $f_{a_i}$ times in the sequence? Lastly when you say "The elements in the sequences need to be in the order they appear in sequence a." can you elaborate on what that means? Are you counting substrings of $(1,1,2)$ in your example?

Comment: In your example, doesn't $(1,1,2)$ count as a sequence, so the answer should be $5$? Or am I misunderstanding? Also, when $a=(1,2,3)$, is $(1,3)$ a valid sequence (must the sequence be consecutive)?

Comment: The full sequence doesn't count. In short, yes, i want to count "subtrings", so the elements don't have to be contiguous.

Comment: The answer depends on the order of the symbols, not just the number of each which appear. These two sequences both have three $1$'s and one $2$, yet different numbers of subsequences.
$$
\begin{array}{rrrrrrrr}
(1,1,1,2):& 1&2&11&12&&111 & 112  \\
(1,1,2,1):& 1&2&11&12&21&111&112&121
\end{array}
$$

Comment: @MikeEarnest So if i give the following information: in the sequence there are $r_1, r_2, r_3, .., r_n$ repeated elements, would it become solvable? Example: If the sequence is $(1, 1, 1, 2)$, the information would be $(3, 1)$.

Answer (score 0):

If your initial multiset has $f_1$ copies of $1$, $f_2$ copies of $2$, etc. then the number of distinct multisets of $$\prod_{i \in \mathbb{N}} (1 + f_i)$$ However, if you want to exclude the original multiset and the empty multiset you must then subtract $2$.